# Python's subprocess.getoutput with non-UTF-8 output

Tags: python, utf-8

Is there a way to have subprocess.getoutput handle output that is not valid UTF-8? If the output of the command comes back with non-UTF-8 characters, it raises an exception. However, there doesn't seem to be an encoding parameter to the function.

```
File "foo.py", line 104, in <module>
  OutText = subprocess.getoutput(TheCmd)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 827, in getoutput
  return getstatusoutput(cmd)[1]
. . .
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
  (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 1495: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: May be wrap it with `try-except` block and surpassing this exception only.

Comment: The coding of the output depends on the command executed and running platform, not rely on the function subprocess.getoutput().

Answer (score 0):

You could try another command `subprocess.check_output` with option `test=True`. and the result of this function is bytes. Then you can manually decode the bytes with correct codec to get the string result. Like this:

```py
import subprocess

cmd = "svn log"
result_bytes = subprocess.check_output(cmd, text=False)
result = result_bytes.decode("gb2312")
print(result)
```